# trying to write a proper if statement in php

Tags: php

i am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to do this... i have a select menu i want to display as default and a different one(s) if certain items appear in a shopping cart.

so say i sell dogs and cars. in the cart i have selected one of each. i want one select menu to appear if there are ever any cars in the cart. but if there are ever any dogs in the cart or cats for that matter i want a different select with different options to appear. so car_select would be the default if anything is in the cart...(i sell a lot of stuff) but if a dog appears in the cart then dog_select would replace it.

the way it is written now. the default is the last thing and that is what shows.
(see my comments)

so the code:

```
<?php
foreach($this->rows as $i => $row){

if (strstr('dogs',$row->dates)) {
$mydates = 'dogs';
} else {$mydates='default';}


//echo $row->dates; this spits out the correct values dogcar


}
//echo $mydates; with a dog and a car in the cart this returns default
//below functions i believe but i think the above is faulty 
?>
<?php 
if ($mydates =='dogs'){
//do something here;} else {

    $type = $this->type;
    foreach($this->extraFields[$type] as $fieldName => $oneExtraField) {
     if ($fieldName != 'pickupdate-rosh'){; ?>
        <tr class="hikashop_checkout_<?php echo $fieldName;?>_line">
            <td class="key">
                <?php echo $this->fieldsClass->getFieldName($oneExtraField);?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php 

                        echo $this->fieldsClass->display($oneExtraField,$this->$type->$fieldName,'data['.$type.']['.$fieldName.']'); 
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

i would like to always return car_select unless the presence of dogs or cats etc in the cart.
{edit: i just realized that is not the correct function to use to look for a string.}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're setting `$mydates`, then overriding it (potentially). This is because you're setting one variable to one result for all iterations of your `foreach` loop, and the last iteration will be what the final variable value will be.

So set `$mydates` to a default and then change it if the condition is right.

```
$mydates='default';
foreach($this->rows as $i => $row){
    if (strstr('dogs',$row->dates)) {
        $mydates = 'dogs';
    }
    //echo $row->dates; this spits out the correct values dogcar
}
```

Comment: thanks, i always get confused in the loop! other question: if i wanted 'dogs' to actually represent another array of the animals that override..  do you do that with another foreach?

Comment: Yeah, these are usually *Doh!* moments for me. As for your second question, I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do.

Comment: well where i search for dogs i actually have like 5 different terms to search for... i was thinking i could make an array(dogs,cats,birds) and then search for all of them in the one if statement, instead of making multiple searches. i thought might be a better way to write it?

Comment: If you have an array of search terms, you could use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead to search one array with another array of needles. Performance may vary, but unless you have a lot of concurrent requests, I would imagine you'd be fine.